# Is the Action passed to PushStreamContent guaranteed to be called?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, pushstreamcontent

The WebApi's [`PushStreamContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995250(v%3dvs.118)) accepts an `Action<>` or a `Func<>` that is named "onStreamAvailable" and is supposed to be

> called when an output stream is available, allowing the action to write to it directly.

**Is that Action (or Func) guaranteed to be called?**

In a situation where the user quickly closes the browser after clicking a link that starts streaming on the server, is it possible that the WebApi framework will not call the lambda at all?

[Background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640): It would be *very very convenient* to pass a certain handle to the `Action`, but it absolutely has to `Close` it. In a situation where the lambda is not called at all, we would end up with a leaked handle.